# Access Raspbian wheezy desktop GUI through ssh

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a Raspberry pi that I have been accessing through SSH, but now I need to run a python program on it that has a GUI. I'm not sure how to do this through SSH. Usually I get to my raspi's desktop gui by typing startx. Is there anything I can do like this over ssh?

Thanks!

Comment: Should be moved to [UL](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do X11 forwarding with ssh. If you start an ssh session with `-Y` or `-X` it'll enable X11 forwarding. So, any program you run in that session that creates a window, the window will be drawn locally. You can also pass `ssh` a command to run :

```
$ ssh -Y user@$some_ip /path/to/some/remote/python_script.py
```

If you want a full gui session, then you'll want to setup an RDP or VNC server on the rasp pi and connect to it with some client.

Comment: combine this with Xnest then you can run the entire raspi desktop embedded in a window on the remote display. I find the performance of this on a lan to be superior to vnc.

Answer (score 11):

The approach mentioned by kjprice just displays the applications you started on the remote host. If you want to see a complete dektop, you could either create a new Xserver or use Xephyr to nest a Xserver in the one you are currently using.

Well first create a new nested Xserver:

```
user@host $ Xephyr :1 -screen 800x600 &
```

A window called "Xephyr on :1" should spawn. Ssh into the remote host an forward the display to the created display:

```
user@host $ DISPLAY=:1 ssh -Y username@remotehost
```

Now start a session on the remotehost, in my case LXDE:

```
user@remotehost $ lxsession
```

You should now see the desktop in Xephyr. hf

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly for starting the remote xsession. However, I am not able to exit cleanly. When I try to logout of the xsession, the lxsession program stops, but the window stays open and operational (it seems the desktop theme is unloaded). What is the preferred method to shut down the session?

Comment: I am not sure if you mean xephyr or sth in it. Xephyr has to be killed via `killall xephyr` as it was started to the background. Just google for bash ampersand.

Comment: The question I have is how to logout of the lxsession that is being displayed in Xephyr, not how to terminate Xephyr. Simply selecting logout from the gui does not log me out of the session.

Comment: I dont know exactly. Its half a year ago. This is up to lxsession. Can you exit LXDE instead of logging off? Or just ctrl-c (kill process) in the terminal running ssh. If lxsession forks to the background try killall lxsession. None of them is proper.